# Gradle updated version crashing

Tags: android, gradle, version

i've got a problem after updating gradle from `3.2.1` to `3.3.2`, I've tried to sync my project and got this error:

```
Gradle DSL method not found: 'x()'
Possible causes:
The project 'Makadu_Android' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.3.2 and sync project

The project 'Makadu_Android' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin
```

However it got tricky, the error message says that I should update gradle to 3.3.2, but I'm already using this version.

Here I'll paste my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    ext.fabric_version = '1.25.4'
    ext.google_services_version = '4.0.2'
    ext.publisher = '1.2.2'
    ext.realmVersion = '5.4.0'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:$google_services_version"
        classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:$fabric_version"
        classpath "com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:$publisher"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:$realmVersion"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
    rxandroid_version = '2.0.1'
    anko_version = '0.10.8'
    rxjava_version = '2.1.7'
    support_version = "28.0.0"
    constraint_layout_version = "1.1.0"
    junit_version = "4.12"
    runner_version = "1.0.1"
    espresso_core_version = "3.0.1"
    retrofit_version = "2.3.0"
    okhttp_version = "3.9.1"
    adapter_rxjava_version = "2.3.0"
    gson_version = "2.8.2"
    retrofit_gson_converter_version = "2.3.0"
    play_services_auth_version = "11.8.0"
    firebase_version = "11.8.0"
    jodatime_version = "2.9.9"
    linkedin_version = "1.1.4"
    facebook_version = "[4,5)"
    glide_version = "4.6.1"
    exoplayer_version = "2.6.1"
    circular_imageview_version = "2.2.0"
    realm_adapters_version = "2.1.1"
    search_view_version = "1.4.0"
}
```

and now goes my graddle-wrapper properties file.

```
#Thu Apr 11 12:06:29 BRT 2019
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```